eclipse java.lang.module.FindException error
I've tried a lot, but I don't know a clear solution.
I searched on Google and searched for 'java.lang.module.FindException' and found a lot of results so I followed it. trything failed. Can you tell me? I've been trying for several days.
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module waffle.jna not found, required by org.mariadb.jdbc



The error message says that waffle.jna is missing on the modulepath when running your application. So make sure that you added this required dependency.

@Abra There isn't really a stack trace when this happens. This is happening before the application is starting. However, it would probably be helpful to show the Libraries tab of the build path (Right-click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries) as well as the pom.xml/build.gradle and whether module-info.java if present.

According to this, waffle.jna is a native Windows Authentication Framework. So are you explicitly using waffle.jna or is it maybe a dependency of something else that you are using?
